# Express the following in terms of $p$ and $q$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\log_{a}x=p$ and $\log_{a}y=q$, express (a) $\log_{a}x^3y^2$ and (b) $\log_{a}\sqrt{xy}$ in terms of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Should either be all $\log_4$ or all $\log_a$.

Comment: Done @JohnHabert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll work out the first question:
\begin{align}
\log_ax^3y^2&=\log_ax^3+\log_ay^2\\
&=3\log_ax+2\log_a y\\
&=3p+2q
\end{align}

Comment: hey thanks...I copied the question wrong in my notebook! Feeling like a fool! :( @Ragnar

Answer (score 3):

Use the formulas:

$$\log_a AB = \log_a A + \log_a B$$
$$\log_a A^n = n\log_a A$$

Answer (score 1):

Kiara, your idea (in the comments) is very good.

$$ x = a^p,\; y= a^q $$

$$ x^3y^2 = a^{3p}a^{2q} = a^{3p+2q}, \; \sqrt{xy} = \sqrt{a^{p}a^{q}} = \sqrt{a^{p+q}} = a^{(p+q)/2}. $$

We immediately get $3p+2q$ and $(p+q)/2$ as answers to your questions.

Comment: hey thanks...um done! :) :D

Comment: @Kiara sure, good luck :).